# Downloading files greater than 2gb via http doesn't work

Tags: windows, http, firefox, download

I am raring up files and downloading them via HTTP from my webserver. 
Most of the files have been below 2GB but now it seems the ones that are round 2GB and higher aren't working.

When I download the smaller files using Firefox or DownloadThemAll, the download manager detects the file size and states something like 3Mb/1.8GB. I can also pause and resume the download.

However, when I try this with files larger than 2GB, it does not detect the file size, but simply states something like 3MB downloaded and also I can not pause the download. After a while the download just fails.

I don't know if file size is the issue here. If not what is the problem, and more importantly - how do I get around it?

UPDATE:

The url looks like this: 
www.myserver.com:8600/dlfolder/images_2250_2499.rar

Comment: is there any http proxy between you and the server?

Comment: @petrus: No proxy.

Comment: Is the problem only with firefox, what happens when you download with IE/Chrome/Curl/Wget?

Comment: @Zoredache: Giving it a bash...

Comment: @Zoredache: IE bombs with "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have an old version of Firefox or Apache. According to [bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=184452), this was fixed in 3.5. Apache fixed this in 2.1.

Update your software and you should be fine.

Comment: I am running Firefox 7 downloading from a server runnning IIS 7.

Comment: The question was updated, suggesting this applies to other browsers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using a workstation with FAT32. This is a limitation of this filesystem. Convert your fs to NTFS with `CONVERT C: /FS:NTFS`. See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307881

Comment: That seems unlikely  FAT has a max file size of ~4GB.

Comment: Indeed the limitation is ~4GB. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314463